# How to know whether the mouse is inside the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseleave

I can't seem to find the answer.

I have a `mouseleave` event, in which I want to check, when the event fired, whether the mouse is currently inside the window or not (if not, it can be the tab bar of the browser, back button, etc).

```
    var cursorInPage = false;
$(window).on('mouseout', function() {
    cursorInPage = false;
});
$(window).on('mouseover', function() {
    cursorInPage = true;
});
$('#some_element').on("mouseleave",function(){
  if(cursorInPage === true){
     //Code here runs despite mouse not being inside window
    }
 });
```

Can I bind to a window `mouseleave` event? If you leave the outside scope of the document/window, does such an event fire? The above code has a problem since i believe the mouseleave of the element fires before the window

Comment: So your question is: Is it possible to detect when the mouse is moved off the page entirely?

Comment: [You can just put the relevant events on the `window` object](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/TdYwe/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just tested this hope it helps. heres the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2A9J/) for it.

```
$(document,window,'html').mouseleave(function(){alert('bye')}).mouseenter(function(){alert('welcome back!')})
```

Comment: +1 for your question actually fire only when needed, but I still encouter the problem that the other event fires first.

Comment: are you talking about the #some_element ?

Comment: can you build a quick jsfiddle to view

Comment: Ya but in there the "4" alert is displayed before the "bye".

Comment: It's not :) my element does reside in top:0 right:0, and to solve it u just moved it a bit,still doesn't really solved it but It's ok man Thank you i just added a delay which kinda solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you're asking us to put for "what to write here?", but you can simply set a boolean:

```
var cursorInPage = false;
$(window).on('mouseout', function() {
    cursorInPage = false;
});
$(window).on('mouseover', function() {
    cursorInPage = true;
});
```

Then use that boolean to proceed:

```
if (cursorInPage === true) {
    alert('Woo, the cursor is inside the page!');
}
```

Here's an [example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/75U4K/) which changes the body background colour when the cursor enters or leaves the window area, better displayed when looking at the [full-screen result](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/75U4K/embedded/result/).

Comment: This works in the fiddle but does not work in my code... I've edited question

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? It's possible that you're using a version of jQuery lower than 1.7 (meaning `on()` isn't supported) - although your question uses that so I assume it is.

Comment: No i'm using a new version. the problem is that the element mouseout event fires before the window one.

Comment: Based on your edited question, surely `cursorInPage` will always be true if `#some_element` is within your `window`. Your cursor will leave that element but it will still be within `window`.

Comment: The thing is the element is in the top right corner, so mouse leave happens sometimes when the user is on the border of the screen.

Comment: You could always use a short [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) to delay the `#some_element` `mouseleave` function to give a bit of time for the `window` function to occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
$('body').mouseout(function() {
alert('Bazzinga...');
});
```

or

```
$(window).mouseleave(function() {
alert('Bazzinga...');
});
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: No. He's asking whether the event fires reliably. You've said "Here's how to hook the event." From his code, it's clear that he knows how to hook the event.

Comment: and millind, the problem with body and window events are that the mouseleave of the element fires before the window

Answer (score -1):

**When mouse is inside element**

```
$('#outer').mouseover(function() {
  $('#log').append('<div>Handler for .mouseover() called.</div>');
});
```

**When mouseleave element**

```
$('#outer').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#log').append('<div>Handler for .mouseleave() called.</div>');
});
```

Comment: what is outer and what is log?

Comment: I am aware how to bind to mouseover events, trying to find out how to detect if mouse is in the window

Comment: @MilindAnantwar #outer and #log can be any element(let say div) id this event trigger when someone mouseover div (having id outer).

Comment: @eric.itzhak i understand your question, you can replace '#outer' with 'body' `$('body').mouseleave(function() {`

Comment: @eric.itzhak check this link i think this question has been solved! [jquery-javascript-check-if-mouse-is-in-or-out-window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958286/jquery-javascript-check-if-mouse-is-in-or-out-window)